# C# Install Font into Windows Font Folder

Tags: c#, fonts, installation

I need to install a font on a client machine when my program is started and I know I need to use PInvoke to accomplish this but I am having trouble understanding what exactly PInvoke does and I don't really understand the example [HERE](http://www.atakala.com/Browser/Item.aspx?user_id=amos&dict_id=83).  Would someone be able to dumb this down to a newbie level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx)?

Comment: PrivateFontCollection can be used to install fonts that do not exist in the operating system. This is a temporary font install that does not affect the system-installed collection

Comment: PrivateFontCollection works perfectly for **TTF fonts** with TrueType outlines but if you try to use **OTF fonts** or **FON files** it will simply crash.