# Install a font silently

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I need to check if a font is not installed on a machine, and if not, for my program to install it with no user interface.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

I know that I need to first copy the font to the font directory but to enable it machine needs to be restarted and I don't want this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616053/c-sharp-install-font-into-windows-font-folder).

And maybe try this:

```
[DllImport("gdi32", EntryPoint = "AddFontResource")]
public static extern int AddFontResourceA(string lpFileName);
```

Comment: That is nice but a demonstration of lack of reading. He does not say "use a font" but "install a font". The above call does REGISTER a font for usage until the session ends - which is not the same as installation into the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Yes. IT IS NOT. Not your job to install fonts - VERY Likely the admin will tell you to go to hell (as in: your program / user has no rights to do so). I have to check, bu tI am quiet positive normal users can not copy fonts to the font directory.

This is what installers do. You COULD start an installer silently, but then you get into the rights issue again, so that wont really work unless the user is - ah - ;) well - not a normal user.

> machine needs to be restarted and I don't want this.

NOONE cares what you want. MS has set up guidelines for installation, they have to be followed. Been there myself - any trick you do will come back and bite you. Humbleness rules here - follow the rules.

Still too much software out written by people with - ah - issues - that write for example config / user data into their folder (Which is write protected now - and was documented so for the last 10 years).